# Find dimension of $S=\{T:V\to V \mid T_{_W} =0\}$ where $W$ is a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be vector space with $\operatorname{dim}(V)=5$ on field $F$ and $W$ be a subspace of $V$ with $\operatorname{dim}(W)=2$.

If $S=\{T:V\to V \mid T_{|{_W}} =0\}$ then what is dimension of $S$ as a subspace of $L(V,V)$?

Answer (score 1):

We can represent any linear transformation from a vector space of dimension 5 to itself as a 5 by 5 matrix so the vector space of all such linear transformations has dimension 25.  The requirement that the kernel (the subspace of all vectors that are mapped into 0) have dimension 2 means there is a basis for V such that the matrix representation of T having the last two rows all zeros.  That leaves 3 rows of 5 numbers each that could have any values.  The dimension is 3(5)= 15.